# Is there any way we can migrate an old but good question?

Tags: support, migration

[Why does my Canon DSLR stop recording video automatically?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/why-does-my-canon-dslr-stop-recording-video-automatically) is a good question with good answers - but is now definitely off-topic here as it's purely about video. It seems to be this would still be a good question on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/), but the "migrate" option is disabled as the question is too old. Is there a way this question can still be migrated, or are we stuck with things as is and should just close this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not by a moderator, either. If the question is too old to move, a moderator can close it and then lock it permanently as "historically significant" which tells people that it's an older question, but not evidence that you can ask a similar one going forward. I've done that for this one (and a few others) now.